# Comparable : Compare the object on various parameter using compareTo

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

I am studying about differences between comparator and comparable interface.

On other sites and even on the stackoverflow it is mentioned that we used Comparator when we need to sort on various fields.

Now i am using Comparable like this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

class HDTV implements Comparable<HDTV> {
    private int size;
    private String brand;
    private int price;

    public HDTV(int size, String brand, int price) {
            this.size = size;
            this.brand = brand;
            this.price = price;
    } 


    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(HDTV tv) {

        if (this.getSize() > tv.getSize())
            return 1;
        else if (this.getSize() < tv.getSize())
            return -1;
        else if (this.getPrice() > tv.getPrice())
            return 1;
        else if (this.getPrice() < tv.getPrice())
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HDTV tv1 = new HDTV(60, "Samsung", 30000);
        HDTV tv2 = new HDTV(60, "Sony", 20000);
        HDTV tv3 = new HDTV(50, "LG", 20000);
        List<HDTV> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add(tv1);
        l.add(tv2);
        l.add(tv3);
        Collections.sort(l);
        Iterator it = l.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
            System.out.println(((HDTV)it.next()).getBrand());
        if (tv1.compareTo(tv2) > 0) {
            System.out.println(tv1.getBrand() + " is better.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(tv2.getBrand() + " is better.");
        }
    }
}
```

the above program help us to first sort on size then on price , means we can sort using two parameters by comparable also.(as per my understanding which is wrong).

Yeah might be this code is wrong but i am not able to figure it out.

I am getting expected order.

Please help me to clarify my doubts.

Comment: You wrote _"I am getting expected order"_ -- If you are getting the expected order, then what is the problem?

Comment: It's kinda weird to have the constructor in-between getters and setters. It's commonly put first.

Comment: see the first point http://www.javatpoint.com/difference-between-comparable-and-comparator

is it wrong ?

Comment: @Andreas changing it , actually i added the price later, so missed it

Comment: @sparsh610 the first point seems bogus to me, you can sort based on multiple elements with both options...

Comment: @sparsh610 and you ignored Jim's comment which is probably the most important one here...

Comment: Well, that is a badly worded article. It's not contrasting single-field vs multi-field sorting, like your example, it's contrasting a single sorting implementation vs. multiple sorting implementations, e.g. there can be only one `compareTo()` implementation, sorting in one way, but you can create multiple `Comparator` classes, sorting in various ways. Whether a "way of sorting" is single-field or multi-field is besides the point.

Comment: Andreas gave you the answer of the main difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

The link you quoted in the comment states:

> Comparable provides single sorting sequence. In other words, we can sort the collection on the basis of single element such as id or name or price etc.

vs

> Comparator provides multiple sorting sequence. In other words, we can sort the collection on the basis of multiple elements such as id, name and price etc.

The confusion here is over the phrase "multiple sorting sequence" and also the fact that the description is incorrect.

What they mean to say is that if you use the `Comparable` interface, then the objects will always be sorted according to that one sequence implemented in the `compareTo()` method.  The sequence can be as complex as you need it to be, based on multiple fields with the object.

When using `Comparator` you provide the collation sequence dynamically, and can implement many different `Comparator` objects that sort the collection in different ways.  This is what they mean by "multiple sorting ssequence".

In both cases, the definition of the comparison can be simple or complex, based on a single field or multiple fields.  Using multiple `Comparator`s you can sort the objects in different ways.

In your example you could make a `Comparator` to sort on brand name, and another to sort on price first, then size.

As to that web page, I would find a better one.  The best reference is always the Oracle documentation.  Learn to read the Javadoc and you'll always get the best information.  It may be a little hard to read sometimes but it's worth the investment.

Comment: `ssequence` -> `sequence` ;-) --- I wouldn't say "dynamically". It's still very static on the call to `sort()`. "Separately" might be better? Unless of course you implement a `Comparator` that is configurable, but I don't think that is what you were referring to.

Answer (score 0):

The comparator and comparable serve two different purposes.. both are used to sort the objects in the way you want. In the above case you can only sort for a specific case where you want tvs to be sorted based on size and price.. 
In future if you want it to be sorted by only price... then you have to change the compareTo method in the above approach. But instead of that you can write an Comparator interface where you can sort the tv elements without changing the class using `Collections.sort(1,new PriceComparator())` . Hope this ans the question.